# Timeout not working in ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am not able to make ajax error callback function of after 3 seconds. I tried with timeout, but it will not switch to error callback after specified time! I am not able to get the alert `Got timeout`.

When I referred similar questions in this site with similar problems it didn't helped out. They all use ajax GET type. I am using jquery 1.10.1 library.

**script :**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  timeout: 3000,
  url : "http://mydomain/Services.asmx/Best_Scores",
  dataType: "text",
  async:false,
  crossDomain:true,
  data: "strJsonRequest="+scoredata,
  success: function (data) {
    // Success code ...
  },
  error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if(textStatus == "timeout") {
      alert("Got timeout");
    }
  }
});
```

Any solution ?

Comment: How long does the RTT take to `http://mydomain/Services.asmx/Best_Scores`? Maybe the url simply does not time out?

Comment: @Amberlamps : Thanks for reply, I will take 15-20 seconds !

Comment: Did you try to alert something in the error function that is not in the if statement? Maybe `textStatus` is not "timeout"?!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

***Fix :***

Change `async : false` to `async: true`

***Reason :***

A synchronous AJAX call blocks until the request has been finished. Implementing a timeout is not possible for technical reasons, because the AJAX call would have to be executed later.

If an AJAX call is executed later, the function somehow has to implement a blocking feature, to stop the code from running further after the AJAX call, and execute it again after a timeout - not possible.

Comment: Is this mentioned anywhere in the JQuery documentation? I could not find it.

Comment: Not sure... But SO is the final destination for developers after all 

Answer (score 5):

Today, (in 2019) I still have this problem.

I have an ajax call too long (depending from Date Start-> Date End) php script.

and after some minutes I get error 500, async: true don't help.

The call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'mymscript.php',
    contentType:'application/json;charset=UTF-8;',
    data: $('[name="myForm"]').serialize(),
    async:true,
    timeout:0,
success: function(response){
...
```

I resolved using:
side PHP:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

at begin of script.

```
echo ' ';
flush();
ob_flush();
```

in the middle of script (for example in main loop every day). This help to let client to don't disconnect (I think that is the main problem).

Using this I continuosly write spaces befor the final json.
Fortunately jquery trim spaces before to parse the json and, in the end, the json is valid.

So I can catch response object to know if script is ended with errors or warnings.

I Hope this help somebody.

Comment: Accepted answer didn't worked for me, but this one did the job. @Mago Maverick Thank You

Comment: This answer also worked perfectly for me in 2022, where the accepted answer didn't solve my issue.